# How to append a string in a specific sets of string in a file

Tags: python, nltk

So I am tagging a corpus and I want to label every stop-words as NOTRELATED. I tried to do it python,  but its not working btw Im just a new in python.

```
 stop_words  = set(stopwords.words('english'))
   for line in word_tokenize(input_file):
      if stop_words in line:
        line = line + " NOTRELATED\n"
 output_file.write(line)
```

Sample Input(text file):
The
cost
of
damage
to
agriculture
and
infrastructure
in
areas
devastated
by
Typhoon
Lando
has 
soared
to
more
than
P6.3
billion
.

Output(file):
The
cost
of  NOTRELATED
damage
to  NOTRELATED
agriculture
and  NOTRELATED
infrastructure
in  NOTRELATED
areas
.
. 
.

Comment: what is the output you get in the file?

Comment: `if stop_words in line:`  this doesn't check if the words in the stop_words are in line. you need to iterate over your `stop_words` set and check every word in it.

Comment: @MaNKuR its blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues. The first is that you should be checking to see if words from the input file are in the stop words set, not the other way around. So

```
if stop_words in line:
```

should be:

```
if line in stop_words:
```

The rest looks mostly like an indentation issue. Instead of writing `line` to the file after the `for` loop completes, write to the file during the loop. And `word` would be a better choice than `line`:

```
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
for word in word_tokenize(input_file):
    print(word, 'NOTRELATED' if word in stop_words else '', file=output_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is the `line` is getting overridden each time loop starts. Try below code and see if this helps.

```
stop_words  = set(stopwords.words('english'))
file_content = set()
for line in word_tokenize(input_file):
    if line in stop_words:
        line += " NOTRELATED"
    line += '\n'
    file_content.add(line)

output_file.write(''.join(file_content))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your output line needs to be in the loop that is actually reading the line. Try this...

```
stop_words  = set(stopwords.words('english'))
for line in word_tokenize(input_file):
    if stop_words in line:
        line = line + " NOTRELATED\n"
     output_file.write(line)
```